# Suddenly reputation drops whereas no indication of it

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation on Stack Overflow drops, but I'm not seeing any notification why a certain amount of reputation has been deducted. It seems like it happens very often. Not sure why this happens, as apparently there is no indication for this deduction.

Comment: I'm not seeing any negative reputation changes since June.

Comment: Strange, I also have not seen any negative reputation. For example, currently my reputation is 1055, but earlier it was 1061. So, not seeing any notification regarding the deduction :)

Comment: If someone retracts an upvote, or unaccepts your answer, you'll lose reputation with no easy way to find out, beyond navigating to your reputation history

Comment: Separately, your suggested edits really need some improvement. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29383402) is an example. Don't use `code` formatting for things that aren't code, _especially_ not links that need to be clickable.  The only useful change that edit made was removing "Sir"; the rest is either superfluous or harmful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've gotten a bunch of reputation from suggesting edits, some of which appear to be on posts that are likely headed for deletion due to quality issues.  When a post is deleted, you lose the +2 reputation for having your suggested edit accepted (because if the post doesn't stick around, your edit isn't providing value to the community).

To see this, open your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current) and click "Reputation", then scroll to the bottom and make sure that "show removed posts" is checked, like so:

[image]

Note that others won't be able to see this on your profile, as you can only see that option on your own profile.

To prevent losing reputation like this, you should make sure that after your edit, the post is good enough to stick around on the site.  There's plenty of guidance in the help center and meta sites that can help you identify which posts meet the site's quality standards.